# How to resize image map with png while remaining aligned?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I recently made a [web-portfolio](https://savior001.github.io/) and I'm trying to make it so my png file uses an image map using this [image-map-resizer](https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/image-map-resizer). But when I try resizing the window, the map doesn't stay aligned with the png. The image map is supposed to underline certain parts of the png when hovered over. How can I get these two to remain aligned?

I've tried messing with some of the attributes I have on my css file, but nothing has worked so far.

### HTML

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=yes, width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <title>Salvador Lopez Jr.</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="portfolio.css">
    <link rel="icon" href="images/favicon2.ico">
</head>
<body id="body" onload="scrollLock()">

<div class="flipContainer">
    <div class="flipper" id="flip">
        <div class="front face">
            <img src="images/card_front.png" width="630px" alt="BusinessCardFront" class="center shadow" usemap="#navmap"/>
            <map name="navmap">
                <div id="undA" onclick="flipToBack(this.id)"><area shape="rect" coords="1480,3255,2330,3480"></div>
                <div id="undW" onclick="flipToBack(this.id)"><area shape="rect" coords="3144,3255,3860,3480"></div>
                <div id="undC" onclick="flipToBack(this.id)"><area shape="rect" coords="4614,3255,5740,3480"></div>
            </map>
        </div>
        <div class="back face">
            <img src="images/card_back2.png" width="630px" alt="BusinessCardBack" class="center shadow" id="scale"/>
            <div id="flipArrow"><img style="cursor:pointer" src="images/flip_arrow.png" width="21px" alt="ReturnArrow"/></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="imageMapResizer.min.js"></script>
<script src="portfolio.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

### CSS

```css
body {
    background-color:#f5f5f5;
    font-family:'Garamond','EB Garamond',
        'Baskerville', 'Baskerville Old Face',
        'Hoefler Text', 'Times New Roman',
        'serif';
    font-size:20px;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    min-width:100%;
    position:relative;
}

section {
    position:relative;
    margin:auto;
    height:100px;
    opacity:0;
    text-align:justify;
    line-height:1.4;
    visibility:hidden;
}

img {
    max-width:100%;
}

#undA {
    position:absolute;
    top:24.1vw;
    left:-14.5vw;
    margin-left:50%;
    width:0;
    height:0.04vw;
    background:black;
    -webkit-transition:0.3s;
    transition:0.3s;
}

#undW {
    position:absolute;
    top:24.1vw;
    left:-3.05vw;
    margin-left:50%;
    width:0;
    height:0.04vw;
    background:black;
    -webkit-transition:0.3s;
    transition:0.3s;
}

#undC {
    position:absolute;
    top:24.1vw;
    left:6.9vw;
    margin-left:50%;
    width:0;
    height:0.04vw;
    background:black;
    -webkit-transition:0.3s;
    transition:0.3s;
}

#undA:hover {
    width:5.28vw;
}

#undW:hover {
    width:4.5vw;
}

#undC:hover {
    width:7.31vw;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you using bootstrap, just add class on your image `class="img-responsive"`, if you dont you can add css code `width:100%`. If you did it already and didnt work, add `!important` to end of your css code.

Comment: I'm not using bootstrap. Would I add `width:100%` to the png's attributes? And would `!important` be on its own, like on a blank line?

Comment: no if your width:100% code is in html, !important is not necessary. But if you gonna add in css you should write like width:100% !important; . That will make your css code more important than your other css codes.

Comment: The code doesn't produce the desired results. It makes the png larger than wanted.

Comment: Than dont use it 100%, make it 50% or whatever you like. If you share your code i can be more helpfull. [link] https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/examples/grid/[/link] Look at this page for using bootstrap.

Comment: I've updated the code with what I thought would help better understand the issue. And the link sends me to a 404 page.